# Convergence in distribution: proof strategy verification (asymptotic normality)

Tags: convergence, asymptotics

Suppose that $X, Y$ are random variables. My aim is to show that $X\overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2)$. If I assume that $X-Y=o_p(1)$ and $Y\overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2)$, is it right to conclude that
$$X=(X-Y)+Y=o_p(1)+Y\overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2),$$
using Slutsky's Theorem?

*$o_p(1):=$ convergence in probability to zero.

Comment: The notation is throwing me off a little because *sequences* of random variables converge in different ways. Individual random variables cannot converge to anything